# Where can I find english version of konosuba light novel online

Tags: konosuba

I recently started reading manga's and I had already watched the Konosuba anime so I wanted to continue the story but since its a light novel I was not able to find it on any manga website so I wanted to know where I can find the light novel online.

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga! Take note that this site doesn't condone piracy, so we will only mention legal/official sites if they exist. Answers/comments that mention questionable sites will be removed without prompt.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your country of origin, the light novel is available online for purchase digitally at please like [Bookwalker](https://global.bookwalker.jp/series/103676/konosuba-gods-blessing-on-this-wonderful-world-light-novel/) and [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s?i=stripbooks&rh=p_27%3ANatsume+Akatsuki&s=relevancerank&text=Natsume+Akatsuki&ref=dp_byline_sr_pop_book_1)/[comiXology](https://www.comixology.com/Konosuba-Gods-Blessing-on-This-Wonderful-World/comics-series/80854).